# How to change font-weight of a text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a button that looks like this:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="top_skin" onclick="theme()">Theme: <span id="dark">Dark</span>/<span id="light">Light</span></button>
```

CSS:

```
#top_skin{display:inline;
float:right;
margin:5px 15px 5px 5px;
padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
height:20px;
min-width:140px;
background:grey;
cursor:pointer;
border-radius:5px;
overflow:hidden;
}

#dark{font-weight:bold;}
```

I want JavaScript to switch the font-weight of the words "Dark" and "Light" so that when I click the button the word "Light" gets bold and "Dark" gets normal. And when I click again I want "Dark" to be bold and "Light" to be normal. But I can't make it work. The funny thing is that I can create a function that do the same thing, but with color in stead of font-weight.

The code that works but changes color instead of font-weight:

```
function theme(){
var dark = document.getElementById('dark');
var light = document.getElementById('light');

if(light.style.color !== "red"){
    light.style.color="red";
    dark.style.color="black";
}else{
    dark.style.color="red";
    light.style.color="black";
}}
```

The code that I thought would do the same thing, but with font-weight:

```
function theme(){
var dark = document.getElementById('dark');
var light = document.getElementById('light');

if(light.style.fontWeight !== "bold"){
    light.style.fontWeight="bold";
    dark.style.fontWeight="normal";
}else{
    dark.style.fontWeight="bold";
    light.style.fontWeight="normal";
}}
```

Thank you!

#### Edit:

Now this time when I try it it seems to work just fine for me too. I suppose there have been a typo somewhere.
Thank you all for your answers, and I am sorry I took your time!

Comment: I expect if you walk through with a debugger, you can figure it out. In 2012, there's really [no excuse](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html) for not using a debugger to debug your client-side code. :-)

Comment: Works for me in Firefox, Chrome, IE7, even IE6 (!): http://jsbin.com/eyabor

Answer (score 8):

It [works for me](http://jsbin.com/eyabor) on Chrome, Firefox, and IE6-9 (well, I didn't try 8). On Opera, though, `fontWeight` comes back as `700` rather than `bold` (which isn't completely unreasonable). So if you're running into trouble on Opera, that may be why.

So you may need to maintain a flag separate from the element's `style.fontWeight` property. One way is like this:

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ejitur) | [Live copy source](http://jsbin.com/ejitur/edit)

```
(function() {
  var lightBold = false;

  // Export just the theme function out of the scoping function
  window.theme = theme;

  function theme(){
    var dark = document.getElementById('dark');
    var light = document.getElementById('light');

    lightBold = !lightBold;
    if(lightBold){
        light.style.fontWeight="bold";
        dark.style.fontWeight="normal";
    }else{
        dark.style.fontWeight="bold";
        light.style.fontWeight="normal";
    }
  }

})();
```

...but of course there are lots of options ([a `data-*` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes), etc.).

Answer (score 1):

why don't you create 2 classes one with normal font, one with bold font and you assign/remove these depending on which class is assigned to an element?
jQuery's [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) and [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) are of great help here